# font-size: .8125rem; is very small when used in a new website

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a webpage that I have been designing in an empty project.  Now I'm moving it to a new project that was a Visual Studio 2019 Webforms project with Master Detail pages, and I converted this page to one of the detail pages.  I coped the script and css files to the new project and I can see it's picking up my original styles.

But every place I used a font-size: 'some number'rem, the fonts render very small.  I'm new to web development and understand that "rem" makes the font size dynamic based on conditions which I don't fully understand yet.  but this was not moved to a mobile app, both the source and target projects are full size website project.

Using the google chrome Inspect feature I could see the style for one of the elements in question.  When I unchecked the font-size attribute, the font rendered more like normal.  Please see the attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is the best way to deal with this type of problem where a page is designed in one environment, then moved to a new environment where non of the fonts render correctly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

'rem' is based on the font-size of html.

For example, if the font-size of html is 16pt(default for chrome), 0.815rem is about 13pt.

If you simply modify the font-size value of html, all font-sizes set by rem will be changed.

```
html {
    font-size: [some number]px;
}
```

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  Where I designed the page the html element had no style so it picked up the browser as you said.  The new-target page (environment) picked up font-size: 10px, probably from bootstrap.css without my knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing `em` and `rem`

- `em` is based on the current font size and `1em` won't change the apparent size.
- `rem` is based on the root font size (html) and `1rem` will be the same apparent size anywhere in the document irrespective of the current font size.

Run this snippet for an example of the differences

```css
:root {
  font-size: 14pt; 
}

.double-size {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}

.point8125rem{
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
}

.point8125em{
  font-size: 0.8125em;
}
```

```html
<p>This text is the root font size (14pt)</p>

<div class="double-size">
  <p>This text is twice the size of the root font size specificied by <code>font-size: 2rem;</code>.</p>
  
  <p class="point8125rem">This text is 0.8125rem, it is based on the root font size (14pt) and is the same as 14pt * 0.8125</p>

  <p class="point8125em">This text is 0.8125em, it is based on the current font size (28pt) and is the same as 14pt * 2 * 0.8125</p>
</div>
```

If you change you CSS to use `0.8125em` then you will probably get the result you are after.

You should seriously consider using rem when specifying font-sizes as using `em` can become an issue with nesting.

Comment: Yes, thank you for clearing this up. I agree and will stick with rem and just set the default font-size in the html element myself.

Comment: Cool, please accept this answer if it helped you. Thanks